# Access - Append query won't append a string input in a texbox form

Tags: ms-access

The form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKgi7.jpg That's where I input the text.
The Query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0L3u.jpg 
The query for some reason does not want to append the strings to the table, it only manages to append the phone number and the ID, and says there's some sort of conversion error which prevents the strings of the name and address from appending.
But ClientName and Address are both data types of short text, so they're supposed to accept a string..

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, I had to use the CStr() function, and it finally worked out somehow.